# Child theme translate

Tags: wordpress, translate

Can anyone help me - I have  read 10 different topics and solutions and I made those changes but this doesn't work

I have created languages folder under metrodir-child theme and put there `pl_PL.mo` and `pl_PL.po` files and I have added to `functions.php` this code

```
<?php
/**
 * MetroDir Child Theme
 *
 * Place any custom functionality/code snippets here.
 *
 * @since MetroDir Child 1.0
 */
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain ( 'metrodir-child',  get_stylesheet_directory() .     '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
?>
```

But the script still shows `po` file from `metrodir/languages` not from `metrodir-child/languages`

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks well and is written as the codex states. Changing domanin name from `'metrodir-child'` to `'metrodir'` should solve the problem. It seems that the domain name should be name of your parent theme.